# What's the procedure when calling fork() then it becomes calling sys_fork()?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

I am checking Linux 0.11.
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/old-versions/

When we finding the function of 'open', we can see:

\lib\open.c

```
int open(const char * filename, int flag, ...)
{
    register int res;
    va_list arg;

    va_start(arg,flag);
    __asm__("int $0x80"
....
```

we have 'open' function which using interrupt 0x80, fine.

However, when checking, 'fork', we can't see it's function as 'open', ex:

```
int fork ( xxx )
{
  ....
}
```

However, we can see something seems related:

```
fn_ptr sys_call_table[] = { sys_setup, sys_exit, sys_fork, sys_read,

#define __NR_fork   2
```

The code seems telling me, yes, sys_fork() is the second function pointer, then you  will get a call to:

system_call.s

```
.align 2
_sys_fork:
    call _find_empty_process
....
```

but how ? and why? why calling fork() will be directed to call sys_fork()?

Comment: I guess the answer is: static inline _syscall0(int,fork)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're looking for *isn't* in the kernel. it is in the C library. Unfortunately the historic C library is not part of the `linux-0.11.tar.gz`, so we can only speculate how it is written.

The C library uses this macro from `<unistd.h>`:

```
#define _syscall0(type,name) \
type name(void) \
{ \
long __res; \
__asm__ volatile ("int $0x80" \
        : "=a" (__res) \
        : "0" (__NR_##name)); \
if (__res >= 0) \
        return (type) __res; \
errno = -__res; \
return -1; \
}
```

with arguments `int, fork` (yes it seems it isn't using `pid_t` as the return value even though that type exists), which will expand to

```
int fork(void) { 
    long __res; 
    __asm__ volatile ("int $0x80" : 
                      "=a" (__res) : 
                      "0" (__NR_fork)); 
    if (__res >= 0) 
        return (int) __res; e
    errno = -__res; 
    return -1;
}
```

This function definition is compiled within *one* translation unit of the C library. Additionally the `unistd.h` file of the kernel is the one made available to the user space.

The inline assembler simply puts the value of `__NR_fork` into `eax`, calls interrupt 0x80 and gets the `__res` return value from `eax`.

The interrupt 0x80 enters `_system_call` from `system_call.s` which has the following code:

```
.align 2
_system_call:
        cmpl $nr_system_calls-1,%eax
        ja bad_sys_call
        [...]
        call _sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
        [...]
        iret
```

i.e. `eax` is first compared against the maximum system call number, and if above, an error occurs; then `eax`th 4-byte pointer is called from the syscall table, and finally `iret` returns from the interrupt, the return value of the called function being held in `eax`.